# GWT 2.7.0 + mGWT 1.2.0 - No tap/touch events dispatched

Tags: gwt, mgwt, touch-event

We have a mobile-web project using GWT 2.6.1 + mGWT 1.2.0

We're now trying to update to GWT 2.7.0 however even if the project runs, no tap/touch event is ever dispatched in Super Dev Mode. None of our TapHandlers are reacting.

Has anyone else experienced and solved a similar issue? Please make sure is for Super Dev Mode.

Comment: I was hoping someone would have an answer for this question

Comment: In which browser does this problem occur?

Comment: The web browser is Chrome

Answer (score 0):

We went to `chrome://flags` and set **Enable touch events** to enabled. This seemed to fix the problem.